# Not getting an ac current output through my speaker in my amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, audio

Will the dc current output affect the speaker, and prevent it from functioning properly? I have already tried different capacitors also change the input voltages and frequencies.

I would really appropriate any help with this problem.

[image: Power audio amplifier circuit]

Comment: what is the purpose of V2? .... the datasheet example uses different components on that pin

Comment: The amplifier produces only 1W into 8 ohms with a 5V supply when it is almost clipping. Your sketch has it badly clipping because the output will try to be 30k/20k x 2.5V x 2.828= 10.6V peak-to-peak. 1W into 8 ohms is 8V peak-to-peak.

Comment: Pin 1 is supposed to be 0V for the amplifier to work or be the positive supply voltage when muted. Your 2.5V will either make it barely work or not work.

Comment: okay i removed the 2.5V from the pin but i just made the  current plot a positive dc current  current still not getting an ac current output

Comment: @Audioguru "1W into 8 ohms is 8V peak-to-peak." - So what? It still won't do too much clipping as the datasheet puts THD at 1W@8Ohm only at 0.25% which is completely acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DC current output?! If you're measuring noticeable DC current on the output (e.g. in excess of 100 mA) then turn the whole thing off, disconnect your speaker and pray that its voice coil is still intact. Seriously though, DC is lethal for speakers, which is why I'm skeptical of ANY opamp datasheet that claims "no output coupling" right at the first page (even if it comes from TI). So before you continue, please, replace your precious speaker with an 8 Ohm resistor instead!

Anyway where did you get that circuit design from? As it's quite wrong in fact. The IC's datasheet (available e.g. at http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4871.pdf) clearly says that "This shutdown feature turns the amplifier off when a logic high is placed on the shutdown pin. The trigger point between a logic low and logic high level is typically half-supply." If you factor in the voltage drop of your power supply then V<sub>DD</sub> definitely won't be 5 volts once you connect it to the opamp and thus 2.5V>V<sub>DD</sub>/2. So basically what you've created is a design that instructs the opamp to stay off all the time.

Anyway once fix your design (i.e. tie pin 1 to ground instead and just throw out the 2.5V thing altogether) you should re-check whether you still have a DC offset at the output. If you do, make sure to put an output coupling capacitor between the opamp's output and the speaker regardless of what the datasheet says.

Comment: alright will try it out

Comment: Koon hey update i used .39nF capacitors to block the dc current and it made the dc current a triangular sine wave instead. and also it made my power on the speaker decrease a lot. any more suggestions?
.

Comment: @devardbain Jesus, a .39 nF capacitor?! That's WAY too small! You know what? Just measure the DC voltage that makes it to your speaker instead. If you get a DC voltage reading of over 500 mV then we can talk about the coupling capacitor again. If not, then it's probably not gonna be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any DC component in the output, Rf should bring the inverting input to match the divider voltage (present at pin 2).

Per the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4871.pdf), the SHUTDOWN pin should be held at 0V or pulled up to Vdd to disable, the transition is at mid-point, so holding it at 2.5V will make it behave unpredictably.